# React DataGrid Cell events

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I've tried to add onKeyDown event for Cell component in several ways, but none worked.
At first I put onkeydown on div here, just like the rest of events here. I also added tabindex=0 to div.
Then put it on ref.

It would be nice to know if somebody had experience.
This cell component is mine and it look a lot like original in source file of datagrid.

Cell component:

```
  function selectCell(openEditor?: boolean) {
    eventBus.dispatch(
      'SELECT_CELL',
      { idx: column.idx, rowIdx: currentRowIdx },
      openEditor,
    );
  }

  function handleCellClick() {
    selectCell();
    if (onRowClick) {
      onRowClick(currentRowIdx, row, column);
    }
  }

  function handleCellContextMenu() {
    selectCell();
  }

  function handleCellDoubleClick() {
    selectCell(true);
  }

  function onRowSelectionChange(checked: boolean, isShiftClick: boolean) {
    eventBus.dispatch('SELECT_ROW', {
      rowIdx: currentRowIdx,
      checked,
      isShiftClick,
    });
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={cn('rdg-cell', column.cellClass, {
        'rdg-cell-frozen': column.frozen,
        'rdg-cell-frozen-last': column.idx === lastFrozenColumnIndex,
        [cnCellValueError]: !!error,
      })}
      style={{
        width: column.width,
        left: column.left,
      }}
      onClick={wrapEvent(handleCellClick, onClick)}
      onDoubleClick={wrapEvent(handleCellDoubleClick, onDoubleClick)}
      onContextMenu={wrapEvent(handleCellContextMenu, onContextMenu)}
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsShowError(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsShowError(false)}
      onDragOver={wrapEvent(preventDefault, onDragOver)}
      ref={combinedRef}
    >
      {React.createElement(column.formatter, {
        column,
        rowIdx: currentRowIdx,
        row,
        isRowSelected,
        onRowSelectionChange,
      })}
      {isShowError && error && (
        <Tooltip
          size="s"
          anchorRef={innerRef as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}
          direction="rightCenter"
        >
          {error.message}
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```